# jQuery: what does this code do?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
l = $("#chat > div.monologue:last div.message:not(.pending):last");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's getting last the  `<div class="message">` that doesn't have a the class `pending"` that's a decendant of the last `<div class="monologue">` that's a direct child of the `id=chat"` element.

Since it looks like you're looking at SO chat code, here's the plain version:
It's getting the last chat message that's not one you *just* sent (and hasn't been confirmed by the server).

Comment: hoho, looks like you are the developer of SO?

Comment: @Bin - nope :) I just helped debugging a bit in the beta so your code's familiar :)

Answer (score 2):

It targets the last `<div class="message">` of `<div class="monologue">` and makes sure it doesn't have `pending` in the class attribute. Now the parent div, which is `<div class="monologue">`, should be the last from its parent div, which is `<div id="chat">`.

To make it clear see below:

```
<div id="chat">
  <div class="monologue"></div>
  <div class="monologue"></div>
  <div class="monologue">
      <div class="message pending"></div>
      <div class="message pending"></div>
      <div class="message"></div>
      <div class="message"></div>

      <!-- it's targeting this div -->
      <div class="message"></div>
  </div>
```